# Check whether string in palindrome : C# code efficiency

Tags: c#, palindrome

I am coming from C background and recently started writing in C# so please don't mind if my question seems somewhat basic. Basically, i want to write a function which will return true if string is palindrome and false if not.

The string may contain characters like space, ',', ':' which i have to ignore. I have written the code as below

```
    static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
    {
        s = s.Replace(" ", "");
        s = s.Replace(",", "");
        s = s.Replace(":", "");

        int j = s.Length - 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < s.Length/2; i++)
        {
            if(s[i].ToString().Equals(s[j].ToString(),StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                j--;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
```

where the function will be invoked with the following string

```
string s = "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama";
```

I read in the documentation that in C#, string are immutable so each time i do a operation like replace or ToString, a new copy is getting created.

So i wanted to check that
i).  Is this code efficient?
ii). If not, how to make it more efficient.

Comment: Don't convert a character to a string, and then compare two characters turned strings. Turning a character (a simple 16-bit numerical value) into a string (an object that will be allocated on the heap and is subject to garbage collection) is the probably the most expensive thing you can do if all you actually want is to compare to characters...

Comment: To improve efficiency, Instead of replacing the characters (which would require to traverse the string 3 times) you could just skip them in the loop that checks for the palindrome.

Comment: If you want to compare characters in a case-insensitive way, turn the characters to either uppercase or lowercase before comparing (`char`/[`System.Char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netframework-4.7.1#methods) has methods for such)

Comment: Your code could be made more efficient by using a `while` loop and 2 variables that point to the start and end of the string. Increment the start value, decrement the end value and just skip characters you're not interested in.

Comment: But this is almost certainly a homework question, perhaps you should ask your tutor?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `.Replace` or create new strings, you can just skip the unwanted characters as you compare.

```
static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{
    var i = 0;
    var j = s.Length - 1;
    while (j > i)
    {
        if (s[i] == ':' || s[i] == ',' || s[i] == ' ')
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        if (s[j] == ':' || s[j] == ',' || s[j] == ' ')
        {
            j--;
            continue;
        }

        if (char.ToUpperInvariant(s[i++]) != char.ToUpperInvariant(s[j--])) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be more readable approach for the Plaindrome detection comparing to the `for loop` you have written:

A short approach but not necessary efficient due to `Array.Reverse` which Reverses the order of the elements :

```
static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{
    s = s.Replace(" ", "");
    s = s.Replace(",", "");
    s = s.Replace(":", "");

    char[] array = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(array);
    string backwards = new string(array);

    return s == backwards;
}
```

A more efficient approach which requires more lines of coding would be :

```
    static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
    {
        s = s.Replace(" ", "");
        s = s.Replace(",", "");
        s = s.Replace(":", "");

        int i = 0;
        int j = s.Length - 1;

        while (i < j)
        {
            if (s[i].ToString().ToLower() != s[j].ToString().ToLower())
                return false;

            i++;
            j--;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Another approach similar to the 2nd one but without the needs of converting the `char` into `String` for comparison:

```
    static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
    {
        s = s.Replace(" ", "");
        s = s.Replace(",", "");
        s = s.Replace(":", "");

        int i = 0;
        int j = s.Length - 1;

        while (i < j)
        {

            if (!char.ToLower(s[i]).Equals(char.ToLower(s[j])))
                return false;

            i++;
            j--;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. Definitely the solution which you gave is much cleaner.

Comment: You can keep the s.Replace for removing the spaces and ' from string.

Comment: Not very efficient performance wise (not critizing your answer, just mention it since the question also is somewhat concerned with "efficiency"). But it is readable and maintainable, so it's okay...

Comment: I think for loop is better reverse create  2nd array

Comment: By the way, your code is not doing a case-insensitive comparision, contrary what is attempted by the code in the question  (note that the code in the question uses `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`).

Comment: @elgonzo, I agree with you. using for loop is more efficient than creating a new array which is caused by the Reverse function.

Comment: This would be horribly slow on large strings.

Comment: @elgonzo I've had this question before, given in an interview. OPs original code is much better, though rather than removing characters, I would use a while loop and just skip them.

Comment: Much better but you are not skipping the ignored charaters (spaces, commas etc.)

Comment: @DavidG, I also added a 3rd option which directly compares the char without the needs for ToString() which one do you think perform better? the 2nd or the 3rd?

Answer (score 0):

This solution should be familiar to you if you're coming from a C background. There's no need to allocate a bunch of new strings; just ignore non-letter characters.

There doesn't seem to be a case-insensitive comparison of `char` values in .NET, so this code assumes that `ToLower(...)` with the current culture is sufficient.

```
public static bool EqualsIgnoreCase(char c1, char c2)
{
    var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    return Char.ToLower(c1, culture) == Char.ToLower(c2, culture);
}

public static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{   
    switch (s?.Length ?? 0)
    {
        case 0:
            return false;
        case 1:
            return true;
        case 2:
            return EqualsIgnoreCase(s[0], s[1]);
        case 3:
            return EqualsIgnoreCase(s[0], s[2]);
    }

    var firstIndex = 0;
    var lastIndex = s.Length - 1;

    // todo: this probably falls on its face for a string with only non-letters
    do
    {
        while (!Char.IsLetter(s[firstIndex]))
            ++firstIndex;
        while (!Char.IsLetter(s[lastIndex]))
            --lastIndex;
        if (!EqualsIgnoreCase(s[firstIndex++], s[lastIndex--]))
            return false;

    } while (firstIndex < lastIndex);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The obligatory short but inefficient LINQ solution:

```
static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{
    return s.Where(Char.IsLetterOrDigit).Take(s.Length / 2)
        .SequenceEqual(s.Reverse().Where(Char.IsLetterOrDigit).Take(s.Length / 2));
}
```

Comment: not that inefficient if ```Reverse``` has a special implementation for string.

Comment: @SamuelVidal Unfortunately [it hasn't](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs.html#e247ee4147678571). It would be trivial to implement, but writing more code defeats the purpose of keeping it short. 

Comment: cool, good to know, you are right [.Net Source line 906](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs). At least you can put the Take before the Reverse.

Comment: @SamuelVidal initially I put `Take` before `Where`, but fails for imbalanced palindromes like `"abb..a"`. 

Answer (score 0):

This program upon execution counts the number of palindromes words/numbers that are present in the sentence and displays them.

```
class Program
{

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Palindrome("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, voluptate mom velit omo esse cillum dolore eu fugiatnulla pariatur. Excepteur non proident est laborum.");
  }

  static void Palindrome(string sentence)
  {
     var arr = sentence.Split(" ");
     List<string> palindromes = new List<string>();
     int count = 0;
     foreach (var str in arr)
      {
        string rev = string.Empty;
        for (int i = str.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
         {
           rev = rev+str[i];
         }
        if (str.Equals(rev,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
         {
           palindromes.Add(rev);
           count++;
         }
              
     }
     Console.WriteLine($"Total palindromes: {count}");
     foreach (var palindrome in palindromes)
      {
        Console.Write($"'{palindrome}' ");
      }
      Console.ReadKey();
 }

}
```